# Android Studio/AVD Help Needed

Tags: android-studio, nvidia, flutter, android-virtual-device

I tried to install flutter with android studio everything is working fine but when I try to running a command "flutter run" my android simulator gives and error which is "An application is using more video memory than available this application will close now"

My System Specs:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600S CPU @ 2.80GHZ
Ram : 8.00 GB
Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit
Hard Disk 1 Tb + 128 GB SSD
GPU Specs
nVidia Quadro 2000 1024 MB
```

Comment: Sounds like http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3553/~/opengl-request-for-more-gpu-memory-than-is-available-meaning,

Comment: graphic drivers are up to date